# Change `node.next` in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm dealing with LeetCode problem 2: Add two numbers.

I write a helper function which inserts a new node to the tail of a linked list.

```rust
    fn insert(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, new_node: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
        if (head == None) {
            return new_node;
        }

        let mut tail = head.as_ref();
        loop {
            let mut node = tail.unwrap();
            if node.next == None {
                node.next = new_node; // the error line
                break;
            }
            tail = node.next.as_ref();
        }

        return head;
    }
```

The compiler complains:

```
cannot assign to `node.next` which is behind a '&' reference.
```

I have tried several ways for several hours. The compilation still fails.

Seems that Rust is quite horrible. Any help?

Comment: Linked lists are pretty horrible in any language. The difference is that other languages enable you to shoot yourself in the foot with them and Rust protects you. Mandatory reading if you want to do linked lists in Rust: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/).

Comment: I'll take a look at the book. Although, it seems to take a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust is not being horrible, it's trying to save your ass from modifying a value that you said you wouldn't modify.

If you want to insert a new node into a linked list, you will need to pass the function a *mutable reference* to the list. And since you're mutating the existing list, there's no need to return anything from the function:

```
fn insert(head: &mut Option<Box<ListNode>>, new_node: Option<Box<ListNode>>) {
    if *head == None {
        *head = new_node;
        return;
    }

    let mut tail = head;
    loop {
        let mut node = tail.unwrap();
        if node.next == None {
            node.next = new_node;
            break;
        }
        tail = &mut node.next;
    }
}
```

[Edit after your comment] You can also accept `head` by value and return something, but you need to make the value `mut`, otherwise you can't mutate anything inside it. And the `as_ref()` calls need to be changed to `as_mut()` as well:

```
    fn insert(mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, new_node: Option<Box<ListNode>>) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
              ^^^
        if head == None {
            return new_node;
        }

        let mut tail = head.as_mut();
                            ^^^^^^
        loop {
            let mut node = tail.unwrap();
            if node.next == None {
                node.next = new_node;
                break;
            }
            tail = node.next.as_mut();
                             ^^^^^^
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to call it as `result = insert(result, new_node);`. But it is OK for the new function definition. I'll try is ASAP.

Comment: @JimJin Edited with an alternative that does that.

Comment: Fantastic! I like the second version. I tried `as_mut()` and still got error. When I see your code I notice that I missed `mut` keyword in the first parameter. Since my code is not submitted and I can't access it in another place, I have to try it tomorrow. Thanks in advance.